# MapActivity with TabHost fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, mapactivity

I'm iOS guy try to move to Android, I need someone to explain/help me what should I do in this situation. I have an app with tabhost fragment(3 tabs). At this moment, I just load 3 different simple fragments, it works fine.

Now, I want to implement MapActivity onto the first tab. Unfortunately, I can't extends it to MapActivity. It is currently extended to Fragment.

I searched over internet, but could find out the perfect solution work around it.

This [link](https://github.com/inazaruk/map-fragment) is one of solution, but it uses LocalActivityManager which is deprecated.

**My question is Can I just load 2 fragments and one separate activity for map into fragment tabhost.** If its possible, can you please walk me through how to implement that?

NOTE: I built my app tabhost fragment base on this [tutorial](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/).

Million thanks from me.

Comment: Hello, Im still need help on this. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one solution would be using this modified version of the support lib there FragmentActivity extends MapActivity instead of Activity:

https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps

Remember that you need to create the MapView object inside the Activity class and pass it to the fragment, in this way:

```
public class MyMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Exchanger.sMapView = new MapView(this, "your_api_key");

    }

    public static class Exchanger {
        public static MapView sMapView;
    }
}
```

and the Fragment will be

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle args) {
        super.onCreate(args);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg, Bundle data) {

        final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) MyMapActivity.Exchanger.sMapView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(MyMapActivity.Exchanger.sMapView);

        return MyMapActivity.Exchanger.mMapView;
    }

}
```

`MyMapActivity` is the `TabsFragmentActivity` in the tutorial you linked.
Remember to use the modified version of the support lib ([download link](https://github.com/downloads/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps/android-support-v4-r7-googlemaps.jar))

**The above method is now deprecated.** 
You can now use a MapFragment:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to implement it now, I have 1 more question is do I need to delete the old support lib?

Comment: Can you explain this line: 

Exchanger.sMapView = new MapView(this, getString(R.string.gmap_api_key));

Comment: You create a MapView object using the API key (i put it in the string.xml file ma but your are free to hard-code it). To obtain api key see here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

Comment: As the way you said, I dont need and XML layout hold mapView where I usually include map API key. Am I correct? Also I see you return return MyMapActivity.Exchanger.mMapView; what is mMapView? is it sMapView?

Comment: Last question, if I want to add drop pins on the map, then I do it in my Mapfragment right?

Comment: Yes, all kind of overlay you need to add it in your fragment.